# Setting up Google sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, array-formulas, google-query-language

I have a sheet that has 2 columns - id and comment. In a new sheet I need a formula that is set up like the following: First column is the id, the second column is the frequency of the id and the third column is a list of all the comments associated with that id.

Currently I got the first two columns working with the following formula but don't know how to add the third column (list of comments):

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IF({1,1},TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE('Oct. 2017'!C:C&CHAR(9)),CHAR(9))))&"","select Col1, count(Col2) group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc label Col1 'ID', count(Col2) 'Frequency'",0))
```

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets are different. Don't tag with Excel when you use Google Sheets. Removing the Excel tags.

Comment: Does it have to be in one formula?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach No, as long as I can get the correct items to appear in each column for the associated id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your formula populates A1 onwards and your sheet with two columns is called `Oct. 2017` please try in C1 and copied down to suit:

```
=join(", ",filter('Oct. 2017'!D:D,'Oct. 2017'!C:C=A1))
```